# Is this too much white space fine as I have put radio buttons vertically for readability

Tags: business-application, white-space

[image: Too much white space!]

Hi All,

As per the usability standard I have kept radio buttons vertically aligned so the task cane be completed. However due to this there is a lot of white space on right hand section - see highlighted in image.

Can anyone provide insights for same?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried experimenting with placing the radio button groups next to each other, instead of stacking them?

That might make them a bit more difficult to scan, but with so few options and groups, that could be a reasonable price to pay in exchange for a more compact layout.

Make sure that the labels for each option are short, enough, though, particularly if you expect any localization for this UI.

[image: Three radio button groups with two options each, placed side by side]

P.S.: May I humbly :) suggest to drop the "Select " bit from the "Select Project" menu label, and just call it "Project" (unless it violates any design guidelines where you work)?

This helps you avoid having multiple form fields whose names all start with "Select ", which makes it harder to scan that entire form, as compared to each label starting with a unique word.

Comment: Thanks Jochen for the comments. I will apply your suggestions and check the design

Answer (score 0):

White spaces around elements are more optimum and pleasing than one chunk of whitespace

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I was wondering for completing the whole task I need to cover the whole screen?

Comment: any comments on above concern?